# What is the purpose of the ecommerce property in GTM event?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

GA4 currently provides two methods for tracking. They are `gtag` and GTM (`dataLayer`).

The [`gtag` method does NOT require the `ecommerce` property](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtag#select_an_item_from_a_list) but the [`dataLayer` method does](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtm#select_an_item_from_a_list).
Example:

```js
gtag("event", "add_payment_info", {
  items: [
    {
      // item's properties
    }
  ]
});

dataLayer.push({
  event: "add_payment_info",
  ecommerce: {
    items: [
      {
        // item's properties
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Is there any difference between the two methods?

I understand that `gtag` will call `dataLayer.push` under the hood. But is there any technical reason that the `ecommerce` property is required for GTM methods or is it just by design?

Answer (score 1):

Use DataLayer as much as you can. Because it can be highly re-use in the Google Tag Mangaer.

The common marketing technology now is not only GA to implement. There are also like Facebook pixel and a lot of pixels that need to be installed.

Most of them has similar Ecommerce feature like `view_item` `add_to_cart` `purchase`.

If you use DataLayer. You can just use the `items` in it and re-assemble to another pixel need.

---

If you use `gtag`. This function will only apply on GA and Google Ads. In the future you still need to implement `facebook pixel` again from begining.

So the point here is once there is a accurate `DataLayer` on the website. It will save times in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It's really useful but it's not the answer I want. I just want to know why GTM required the `ecommerce` property

Comment: oh sorry. in this way. GTM designed to read the `ecommerce` parameter by some default feature for GA4 ecomerce. Here is some information link https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/use-ga4-schema-in-universal-analytics-ecommerce/

Comment: The article you referred to is for UA. I'm looking for the official docs from Google. But seem like there is no article written about it explicitly

Comment: Seem like Google recommends using the `gtag` API for GA4 and the `ecommerce` property is for UA events https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/migration/ecommerce/gtm-ga4-to-ua#4_enable_the_gtagjs_api

Comment: I think Google recommend for `gtag` is about migrating UA to GA4. Because there are a plenty or user using `ga` function before. If they can change to `gtag`. They can easily migrate to GA4. Using GA4 only then datalayer should be still a better choice.